# How to fix Hosmer-Lemeshow Error for my GLM in R

Tags: r

Here is my data I'm working with on R. I'm trying to conduct a logistic GLM regression.

```
  defense  gdp pol_violence deliberal instabilityold polityold
1        1  247            1         0           3.09        -7
2        0 1776            1         1           2.79        -2
3        1 1322            1         0           2.09        -9
4        0  102            0         0           2.79        -5
5        0  136            0         0           3.20         4
6        0  703            1         0           3.09         0
7        1 2791            1         0           2.00        -3
8        1 3264            1         1           2.79        -3
9        1  767            1         1           3.20        -2
10       0  203            1         0           2.09        -9
11       0  357            0         1           2.09        -8
12       1  315            1         0           2.80        -7
13       1  190            0         0           1.70        -9
14       0  213            1         1           3.20         8
15       1 1817            1         0           2.80        -8
16       1  319            1         1           1.70        NA
17       0 3369            1         1           3.09         9
18       0  509            0         0           3.09         3
19       0  455            1         1           3.20         8
20       0 1364            0         1           2.70         9
21       1  955            0         0           3.20        -3
```

I used this code for GLM logistic regression and it worked.

```
h1 <- glm(pol_violence ~ defense + gdp + polityold + instabilityold + personalist + military_dic
          , data = dataset)
summary(h1)

h2 <- glm(deliberal ~ defense +  gdp + polityold  + personalist   , family  = "binomial" ,  data = dataset)
summary(h2)
```

After I ran the code for my logistic regressions I tried to run the hoslem.test to test the goodness of fit test  since both of my dependent variables are binary

so whenever I do this:

```
h1 <- hoslem.test(dataset$pol_violence, fitted(h1, g=10)
or
h2 <- hoslem.test(dataset$deliberal, fitted(h2), g=10)
```

**I get the error message:
Error in model.frame.default(formula = cbind(y0 = 1 - y, y1 = y) ~ cutyhat) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'cutyhat')

> **

my dataset consists of 22 country observations with the years in which a military intervention occurred during a popular uprising. my hypotheses are H1: the stronger the military veto power during the uprising, the more likely there is political instability H2: the stronger the military veto power during the uprising, the more likely there is deliberalization

my independent variable military veto power is operationalized with the variable "defense" which expresses whether the defense minister is a military officer (then its coded as 1) if not, its coded 0.

my dependent variables are pol_violence which expresses instability. its coded 1 if there is political instability and 0 if there is non.

same goes to the other dependent variable deliberal which expresses deliberalization. 1 if there is deliberalization , 0 if there is non.

the other variables are control variables, 2 of them (personalist and military_dic) are binary and are coded 1 if there is a personalist leader or a military leader, 0 if non.

gdp is self explanatory. instabilityold expresses instability rate from the year before, the higher the number the more instability

polityold is the polity iv democracy rate from the year before, the higher the number the stronger the democracy.

help me pls. how should I fix the error message? I need to run the code of the hoslem.test

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the hoslem.test() function the argument fitted() pertains to the fitted values from your glm model, not the raw dataset. Also you have an NA value in the polityold column which you have to either leave out of the analysis or impute somehow. For example with a mean or median (which might introduce some statistical problems, like underestimation of standard errors, so you might want to look into that). In your code it should be something like:

```
h1 <- hoslem.test(dataset$pol_violence, fitted(h1), g=10)
h2 <- hoslem.test(dataset$deliberal, fitted(h2), g=10)
```

Comment: Hey. I tried this out but I still get the same error message?

Comment: I missed that you also have a NA value in the "polityold" column. This is what is causing the error. You have to come up with a solution to for that row. To either remove it or impute it with a mean or median are some simple solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error that caused this question. And after trying different solutions, as a last resort I tried renaming the columns to "y" "x1" "x2" etc. then hoslem.test worked

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33078973)